# Questions regarding the command: "net use * http://myserver.com"

Tags: security, iis, filesystems, webdav, mappeddrive

Apparently I'm able to `net use * http://servername.com` and this concept is completely new to me.

Does this mean I'm using WebDAV?

What are the security implications?

How can I read/write files in this manner?

Why doesn't it work for every website?

Is it possible to write files using this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are using WebDAV.

Security implications are, among others things, the fact that Windows leaves a copy of all files in a cache area, for all to see, which can't be disabled.

The server will need to have WebDAV enabled and configured for this to work, and in order w to write, you must authenticate to the server with credentials that are allowed r/w access.

Comment: ... no kidding, every local user on a client can see webDAV data from other users?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, you are using WebDAV.
2. On Windows XP and Server 2003 "net use" supports only NTLM and Kerberos authentication. On Windows 7 and Vista you can use Basic via HTTPS, Digest, NTLM and Kerberos are supported. I would suggest taking a look at this article: http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/map_drive
3. After "net use" you will have a drive mounted in your local file system. Now you can create, delete, copy, move, read files and folders. Just use any file manager, command line tools or any API that works with file system.
4. Most websites does not provide WebDAV access.
5. Yes, you can write files. Just use any API or software that can work with local file system.